# Не прокручивается контент в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, material-design, coordinator-layout, nested-scrollview

Столкнулся с проблемой NestedScrollView и CoordinatorLayout, в верхнем тулбаре имеется картинка, я пытался сделать так, чтобы при скролле вверх картинка уезжала, чтобы остался только тулбар. Сделать то сделал, но теперь контент в NestedScrollView скролится ровно на столько, на сколько уезжает вверх картинка, а остальной контент просто невидно. Подскажите, как исправить?

Код разметки:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_details_wide_poster"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:alpha="0.7"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/movie_details_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_backspace_24"
                    app:menu="@menu/details_tool_bar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/movie_details_progress"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:indicatorType="circular"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:indicatorColor="#00D277"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/movie_details_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView"
                    android:layout_width="133dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_poster"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_release_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Release: 16.02.1999" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_runtime_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_release_text_view"
                    tools:text="Runtime: 2 hr 16 mins" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_rating_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_runtime_text_view"
                    tools:text="Rating: 7.0/10.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_budget_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_rating_text_view"
                    tools:text="Budget: $200,000,000 USD" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_revenue_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_budget_text_view"
                    tools:text="Revenue: $322,613,780 USD" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_genres_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_revenue_text_view"
                    tools:text="Genres: Action" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_line_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="#000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Описание"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_line_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_overview_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Пробовали устанавливать `ConstraintLayout`'у оба параметра `match_parent`?

Comment: @web_alex Пробовал, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Поэкспериментировав, понял следующее: контент прокручивается нормально, не показывается только самый конец. Проблема заключалась в том, что `NestedScrollView` имеет `layout_height="match_parent"`, при этом мой `MaterialToolbar` имеет `layout_height="?actionBarSize"`. Таким образом, не отображалось как раз последние `?actionBarSize` dp. Решил проблему добавлением в `ConstraintLayout` атрибут `layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"`